# Does NuttX rtos (NXP Kinetis KEA) include support for Controller Area Network (CAN)?

Tags: embedded, rtos

I am trying to get CAN up and running on the RTOS NuttX (NXP Kinetis KEA). I was wondering if anyone knew about or could tell me if NuttX has any kind of support for CAN as I was unable to find any could anyone from the community either corroborate that there is no support for CAN on NuttX or provide resources if there are?

PS: I am a completely green to embedded systems so any help is appreciated!.

Comment: The answer to "Can NittX support CAN" is yes in any event (and for ano other OS for that  matter). Specifically "Does Nuttx include support" is a different question and probably whet you intended to ask.

Answer (score 2):

CAN driver support is listed here: http://nuttx.org/doku.php?id=nuttx#device_drivers.  It is mentioned in detail in the [porting guide](http://www.nuttx.org/Documentation/NuttxPortingGuide.html#candrivers)

> **6.1.5 CAN Drivers**
>
> NuttX supports only a very low-level CAN driver. This driver supports
>   only the data exchange and does not include any high-level CAN
>   protocol. The NuttX CAN driver is split into two parts:
>
> 1. An "upper half", generic driver that provides the common CAN interface
>      to application level code, and
> 2. A "lower half", platform-specific
>      driver that implements the low-level timer controls to implement the
>      CAN functionality. Files supporting CAN can be found in the following
>      locations:
>
>    - **Interface Definition**. The header file for the NuttX CAN driver resides
>        at include/nuttx/drivers/can.h. This header file includes both the
>        application level interface to the CAN driver as well as the interface
>        between the "upper half" and "lower half" drivers. The CAN module uses
>        a standard character driver framework.
>    - **"Upper Half" Driver**. The
>        generic, "upper half" CAN driver resides at drivers/can.c.
>    - **"Lower Half" Drivers**. Platform-specific CAN drivers reside in
>        arch//src/ directory for the specific processor
>         and for the specific  CAN peripheral devices.